# How do I merge code in to main-branch in Github?

Tags: git, github, merge

In my repo I have two branches, `main` and `new`. In `main` I have a mockup, some img and pdf-files. In `new` I have all html and css code.

How do I merge or add the `new` branch in to `main`?

Comment: ```git checkout main``` (so you set yourself on the target branch), and then, ```git merge new```. Try this, to learn git: https://learngitbranching.js.org/, and https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

[Atlassian's Git Merge tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge) covers this well.

Short version:

```sh
git checkout main
git merge new
```

With explanatory comments:

```sh
# switch to the "main" branch
git checkout main

# merge the "new" to our currently active branch ("main")
git merge new
```

`new` will still exist after this operation, but `main` will now contain the changes that you'd committed to `new` prior to merging.